# How to enable horizontal scroll bar for html UL list

Tags: css

I have following css for my list. I can see the horizontal scroll bar but its disabled. How to enable it?

```
 .li {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10; 
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px; 
  max-height: 20em; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;

  }

 .ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 4px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   max-width: 10em;

   white-space: nowrap;
   color: black;
   cursor: pointer; 

   }
```

Please help

Comment: Please post your HTML too.

Answer (score 1):

Your scroll bars are actually `disabled` because you content is not overflow within container. When you have more content that is overflow within parent container. it will automatically works(scroll will be enable)

```
li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10; 
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px; 
  max-height: 50px; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  }
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/DHKj5/12/)

PS: you can also use `overflow:auto` which shows the scroll bar only when your content overflow within parent container.

Comment: For compatibility you might as well use `overflow:scroll;`

Answer (score 1):

Why did you write ".li" and ".ul"? Unless these are your class names for the list elements, they should either just be "li" and "ul" (without the periods), or be the class names of the respective "li" and "ul" elements.

Comment: This is an answer - especially if the OP expects to actually see these styles on uls and lis

Answer (score 0):

First of all the height of the UL must be greater than the size of the UL.

So you can do like

.li { 
  position: absolute;
  width:10px;
  z-index: 10; 
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px; 
  max-height: 20em; 
  overflow-x: scroll;

}

and the content size must be greater than 10px.Then you can view the scrool.